py3-tts comtypes issue with just_playback
I'd like to use both just_playback and pyttsx3, if possible.
Currently it works, but trouble is that I get some "info" messages which I don't understand.
Minimum working example
import pyttsx3
from just_playback import Playback
engine = pyttsx3.init()

Message I get:
INFO: Imported existing <module 'comtypes.gen' from '.../AppData/Roaming/Python/Python311/site-packages/comtypes/gen/__init__.py'>
INFO: Using writeable comtypes cache directory: '.../AppData/Roaming/Python/Python311/site-packages/comtypes/gen'

Have tried ignoring these messages by using shutup or warnings, had no effect.
A workaround would be python testfile.py 2> logs.txt, however I'd like to avoid this as it mutes any other error messages as well.
What else can I do?
Any idea to fix the underlying problem itself, or to just get rid of that info.
For reference:
https://github.com/cheofusi/just_playback/tree/main
https://github.com/thevickypedia/py3-tts
